# What is the socket for on this Baofeng BL-5L battery?

Tags: baofeng, battery

I have a Baofeng BL-5L battery for my Baofeng UV-5R transceiver, and I notice that it has a socket on the side:
[image: as in the image]

Please, what is this socket for?

Comment: It is a charging port, but it is not the same size as the plug on the stand-up chargers.  Myself, I just charge them in the stand-up chargers, and even picked up a 12 Volt adapter for them.  In any case, check out the answers below for further explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's for charging a 3800mAh battery using the side jack.
To charge the BL-5L 3800mAh battery you must purchase a:
- TYT TH-UVF9 battery charger for 110VAC  or
- TYT TH-UVF9D  for 12VDC.

- These are fully regulated chargers
- Plugs directly into side of battery, not a charger base
- The AC wall wart has a charging indicator.
   Red while charging, Flashing Green Red when charged.

Comment: Welcome @user8635!  Thanks for your complete answer to the question.  (I took the liberty of editing it to tweak the grammar a bit.)  We recommend all new users take [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour).  If you like, you can change your username later to be something more memorable.  Again, welcome!

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses. Unfortunately I can mark only one as the answer, but I have up-voted both.

Answer (score 3):

Check point no 6.7 on this page - http://www.miklor.com/uv5r/UV5R-FAQ.php#Batteries

It talks about an extended battery like you have shown here. Also says that it uses a side jack. The port you see here is probably for the side jack.

Answer (score 0):

BaoFeng BF-F8HP 100% backwards compatibility claim:
In the document referenced above,
*"Check point no 6.7 on this page - http://www.miklor.com/uv5r/UV5R-FAQ.php#Batteries"*
it's inferred that since 3800mAh battery pack is compatible with UV-5R it's also compatible with BF-F8HP (based on BaoFeng claims BF-F8HP is 100% backward compatible with UV5R accessories, I suspect)...however...

There are ads on ebay that **specifically stipulate their BL-5L 3800mAh is NOT compatible with BF-F8HP even though compatible with UV-5R**. So, BF-F8HP compatibility is not 100% backwards compatible with UV-5R fitting accessories. I verified this by purchasing and checking. While slightly more difficult to slip onto a UV-5RTP case than the 1800mAh pack that came with the radio, the BL-5L battery packs definitely had to be firmly pushed to engage the eject tab on the F8HP.
I wrote baofengtech.com and they insist BF-F8HP is 100% compatible with all UV-5R accessories. I realize we're talking a non-Baofeng accessory, but if an accessory fits a UV-5R many folks would think "backwards compatibility" would ensure it fits an F8HP.

So, the lesson of this is...don't ASSUME compatibility based on model numbers and Baofeng-ish claims...read every product description fully. The warning on this UV-5R=compatible, but BF-F8HP=incompatible was listed WAY down on the product page.